# HDFS-Redundant copies

Tags: hdfs

- Does the initial copy of file which is placed in HDFS is also split across data nodes along with the redundant copies?
- Because we are able to view the HDFS file as a whole in the path which it is placed.
- If there's an internal mechanism to split the file,please help in explaining the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the initial copy of file which is placed in HDFS is also split across data nodes along with the redundant copies?

Answer is Yes.

> If there's an internal mechanism to split the file,please help in explaining the same.

You can check the details of a file using the following command:

```
$ hadoop fsck /user/aaa/file.name -files -locations -blocks
```

Comment: Hi Rajat,thanks for your time.This shows the data nodes where the copies are stored.anyway to check if i could access the data node where the other copies are placed.also my file is a zipped file.How will the HDFS/Hadoop treat the different formats.

Comment: As far as the zipped files are concerned the behavior would be same.